# Auth key for private GitHub repo with Paket

Tags: github, f#, paket

The [paket docs](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/github-dependencies.html#Referencing-a-private-GitHub-repository) show how to reference a private GitHub repo but the [config docs](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-config.html) section isn't particularly illuminating on the particulars of how to set up the 'GitHub Auth Key'.

In particular, I am not sure from reading this what I should be using as arguments.

I have tried `packet config add-token "http://github.com" [my github personal access token]` but get the following error when running `paket update`:

> Paket failed with:
>           Could not find hash for `https://api.github.com/repos/[my username]/[my private repo]/commits/master`

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Michael